# System unresponsible - extreme load

Tags: debian, systemd, load

Today my server became unresponsible I could not even log in to ssh, but as I am running my own server app on it I was able to recover a "top" data.

Server was running but was not accepting any new connections however my app was still sending output of "top" command to my web interface:
2% CPU usage
0.0% wa
load 110 ? how ?
[image: top]

I found something suspicious in syslog:
https://pastebin.com/u8kLCJEM

It was there like 10 times and then no more messages in syslog when I came (1 hour later) I just screenshoted the top (110 load) and completely restarted the server and its going fine. But I want to know why my server crashed and how can I prevent it ?

Comment: If you could show the content of `/proc/13166/maps`, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any very suspicious in your systemd logs.

What I can see:

- You have a JVM (java virtual machine) eating up ≈ 64GB RAM
- You have 64 GB physical RAM
- You have no swap

So, this is the cause of your problem. Your JVM is leaking.

You have to somehow kill it, and then restarting it.

The reason, why your top and web console works, that there is a little bit of free memory, and they were already running, as your JVM went mad. Thus, they don't need to allocate too much RAM, and the few they use, they can.

Other things, what you want to start, aren't so lucky. For example, your sshd seems incapable to fork a new process (and, a new shell).

JVM likes to eat many RAM, but not so many. 64GB is extreme. Something is not okay in the web application, what is hosted by your server. What exactly, it could be found only by deeper inspecting the web app running on it.

To make your system working, first you have to somehow kill that JVM. From command line, a simple `kill -9 13116` would do the task, but you now don't have command line.

However, a command line `top` *can* kill processes (press k, select the PID), maybe the same feature exists also on your web-based top.

If nothing works, you have to reboot.

---

On the long-term: you should play with the JVM flags and limit its memory usage. Somewhere in an .ini file, you can set up flags for it, these are: `-Xmx<number> -Xms<number>`. Check these. The details depend on your application server.

Such RAM rampage is not common from Java, something is not okay in it. Only knowing your app could be said exactly, what is it.

Security breach, I can't see in your log.

Comment: No, look my JVM is not consuming all the ram, there is 35 GB of memory used for cache by the OS (debian).

Comment: @Welite Right, but the virtual memory used by your java process is still 64GB. Actually, more that 64GB. Isn't it some virtualization, maybe openvz?

Comment: The JVM might have allocated a big chunk that it isn't using yet, so the memory is overcommitted.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Ok, but then why is it in cache? I think it would suggest some mmap(), which is uncommon from a jvm, although not impossible. Maybe it is an in-process db file? Hsqldb?

Comment: I have "used" memory on all of my machines almost 100% but half of it is cache and when some process needs more ram, the ram is allocated from cached ram. I have never run into problems with ram. Even this is not ram related problem. Also all of my JVM processes are limited by xmx flag and on this machine all processes in total have only 42 GB as max.

Comment: @Welite Ok, it narrows the problem a little bit, however your top still says a roughly 69G using JVM. How can it be possible? Maybe it mapped in something. Aren't you use some big, in-process database? | Isn't your machine a virtual machine, or it is bare metal?

Comment: @Welite You know, having swap doesn't make your system slower, it makes faster. It is because the not used memory pages can be made free, and then used as block cache. The "idea" that "I don't use swap so my server will be fast", is simply false, it will be slower and it will have such lockups as you have now (except if you can *really* limit the memory usage, what seemingly didn't succeed now in your case - you say you limited it to 42G, but it eats 69G).

Comment: Ah you mean the virtual memory is 69 GB ? I have disabled swap because once the server starts swapping my CPU wait time for I/O is over 50% and my load goes really high.

Comment: @Welite This solution remembers me to the Chernobyl disaster. There, the alarming/safety system avoided the operators from doing unsafe things. Their solution was: they turned it off. If your system start to swap so heavily, it is because it doesn't have enough RAM, or your JVM was sub-optimally configured. If you turn off the swap on such a system, you will get exactly this lockup (alternatively, your JVM could have been killed by the famous "oom killer"). The correct solution had been to find out, why the JVM needs so many ram, and eliminate its reason (or, to buy more RAM).

Comment: @Welite Btw, it doesn't matter, how many RAM do you have, if you have swap, it makes your system *faster*, even in the case if your RAM is highly underused. Beginner sysadms typically don't understand it, and somehow I feel, also you don't. Thus, I don't have the hopeless goal to convince you, I think you can go on your own way. However, I know what I had done in your case, and what should you do to avoid the lockup.

Comment: The reason why I always disable swap is that sometimes the machine starts to swap even though there is some free ram and once it starts swapping all my running apps will freeze because of system load going high.

Comment: Without swap you get a sudden death spiral. With swap, you get gradual performance decline with more time to intervene to resolve an issue. Either way, if the system is using too much RAM, the underlying issue needs to be resolved. @peterh is giving good advice.

Comment: @Welite It is only an optical illusion: you compare the speed of a swapless and empty system to the speed of an overloaded one. I really won't hurt you, but I absolutely can't see the reason, why should I convince you, why should I enforce you, to make *your* system correctly. Yes, you can do without swap, but then you have to guarantee that all of your apps won't overuse the RAM, and you can't do that. Furthermore, having swap, *with the same load*, will result faster machine. Yes, it will be faster. Make independent benchmarks and you will see, that it is faster.

Comment: @Welite Once I will write a self-answered post, why should you have swap. Now I don't think I have time for the task, so if there is no new thing to talk about (for example, how can you fix your JVM flags which look exactly similarly so f*ed as your virtual memory settings), then I think here our talk ends.

Comment: @peterh I am thankful for your advice I just wanted to explain why I decided to torn off the swap because even with only one JVM app it was sometimes using the swap which caused a huge lag spikes in my app. I dont know how exactly VIRTUAL memory works in linux and I have no idea how it could take up to 69 GB, my settings of JVM are just default if you mean some configuration, when I am staring my JVM apps I just use flags to set initial memory and maximum memory nothing else.

Comment: @Welite I explained, what you should do, you won't understand in the lack of competence. I really can't understand what else you want from me. Our talk **ends** now. Don't count with more reaction.